# undefined method 'random_generate' for #<Generator:0x4cce798>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have a method which i wan to call from my controller. What i've read in stacks are most of them said to include the method in applicationController.Therefore i did. But still i got the following error. Can some1 help me ? New to rails

APPLICATION CONTROLLER :

```
helper_method :random_generate

   def random_generate
     length = @generator.primer_length
        chars = 'ATGC'
        seq = ''
        length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
       @generator.random_primer_generated= seq
    end
```

CONTROLLER :

```
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :generate_option, only: [:create,:edit]
  helper_method :random_primer_generated
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def generate_option
    if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
        @generator.random_generate
    end
    @generator.save!
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length, :choice, :random_primer_generated)
    end
end
```

VIEW:

```
<%= form_for (@generator ) do |f| %>
  <% if @generator.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@generator.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this generator from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @generator.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <label>Primer Length</label><br>
       <%= f.number_field :primer_length %>
  </div>

    <label>Selection :</label><br>
    <label>Randomly</label>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:choice, 'Randomly')%>

<%= button_to('Generate',generate_option_generator_path(@generator))%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it just me or shouldn't you have `random_generate` instead of `random_primer_generated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `random_generate` on the `@generator`, you have to implement that method in the `Generator` class. What you have done is implemented it in the `ApplicationController`, so you would have to call it without referencing to `@generator`.

Also, I think calling `helper_method :random_generate` is only required if you want to call `random_generate` as a controller method inside of a view.

Comment: how do i implement the method to my generator class ? ( i mean where should i place them ?) . 

Is this why they said if we put a method in ApplicationController , we're actually giving the method accessible to all CONTROLLERS ?

Comment: I'm trying to call the random_generate in my VIEW actually. I want to pass my value to the method RANDOM_GENERATE but because i have lots of choice either generate via random_generate or another function which i haven't include in my code.

Comment: The problem is that `@generator.random_generate` calls the method on `@generator`, but you defined the method on the controller. Either call it without `@generator`, or implement the method in the `Generator` model class.

Comment: erm i know it sounds stupid but could u tell me the difference between writing my method in ApplicationController and GeneratorController ? If i write them in APplicationController then the method will be available to all CONTROLLERS ?

Comment: You don't seem to understand. `@generator` is your MODEL. It does not know about `random_generate`, because that is defined on your CONTROLLER. Either you call your method just like this: `random_generate` instead of `@generator.random_generate`, or you move the method to the model. You should be able to call it from the view either way.

Comment: THanks it's fixed now. Thank you so much for making me clear alittle bit of MVC >< ... New to rails n no experience on PHP